# Check if Timer is running

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, nstimer

I have been trying to refill in game lives with a timer, but whenever I leave a view and return, the timer duplicates and becomes faster. I have tried to address this with the `Timer?.isValid` function to only run the timer when it is invalid so it never duplicates, but it cannot seem to check is the timer is **invalid** in an if statement.

This is the if statement that I have been using so far:

```
if (myTimer?.isValid){
} else{
//start timer
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you starting the timer in `viewWillAppear`? More info will be helpful.

Comment: Reallocating a timer or setting it to nil will not invalidate it. Set up the timer once (in 'viewDidLoad' for example) and then invalidate it when you don't need it.

Comment: You should deactivate your timer when u leave your view e.g. use in viewWillDisappear

`myTimer?.invalidate()`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recommend to use self-checking `startTimer()` and `stopTimer()` functions, the timer will be started only if it's not currently running, the stop function sets the `timer` variable reliably to `nil`.

```
var timer : Timer?

func startTimer()
{
    if timer == nil {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer...
    }
}

func stopTimer()
{
    if timer != nil {
       timer!.invalidate()
       timer = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: im not sure if you understand, i want to check if a timer is running, not start/stop a timer

Comment: Your code in the question implies: *If the timer is not valid (is not running), start it*. That's exactly what `startTimer()` does. In my suggested logic the timer is not running if it's `nil`.

Comment: Sorry, I understand now and your function is working!

Answer (score 4):

You need to check if your `Timer` instance `isValid` (not the `Timer` class), let's say: `if myTimer.isValid? {}`.